# Can we get chrome browser's history/bookmarks in our android app, without rooting the phone?

Tags: android, sqlite, google-chrome, android-contentprovider

I already tried [can we get chrome browsing history/bookmarks in our android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137339/can-we-get-chrome-browsing-history-bookmarks-in-our-android-app). Its giving me Error as "Failed to find provider info for com.android.chrome.browser".

Answer (score 0):

i dont know for google chrome but for default browser, here's the code

```
Cursor mCur = activity.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        if (mCur.moveToFirst()) {
            while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                Log.v("titleIdx", mCur
                        .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
                Log.v("urlIdx", mCur
                        .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am able to get history and bookmarks from default browser. Issue is in getting history and bookmarks from browsers other than default browser(Google Chrome) , need solution for that.