# How to retrieve and display browser history and bookmarks in browser application

Tags: android, android-listview, browser-history, bookmarks

Hi friends i am new to android I don't know how to retrieve and display history in web browser.

Please guide me and share your thoughts, ideas and bookmarks too.

I have to display history in `ListView`

Comment: try out this                                                                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137339/can-we-get-chrome-browsing-history-bookmarks-in-our-android-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList mTitles=new ArrayList();
ArrayList mUrls=new ArrayList();



 public void getBrowserHist()  {
            Cursor mCur = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                    Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
            mCur.moveToFirst();
            if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                    Log.v("titleIdx", mCur
                            .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
                    Log.v("urlIdx", mCur
                            .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
                    mCur.moveToNext();
               }
          }
    }
```

Add below uses-permission into your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
```

Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getContentResolver` to get the browser history as `managedQuery` has been depricated.

```
String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, sel, null, null);
mCur.moveToFirst();
String title = "";
String url = "";
if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
    boolean cont = true;
    while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false && cont) {
        title = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
        url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
        // Do something with title and url
        mCur.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Also add permissions in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

For more details to access data using `Cursor` check [Access Data using Cursor](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/3/)