# Detect opened url in default browser

Tags: android, browser, browser-history

I am trying to get the recently opened url from the default web browser. 
As per now i was using this same functionality bellow 5.0 and this is not possible in  5.0 or above . as per my R&D over the internet . Many question has been asked but all are unanswered.

But on the same hand : Norton Parent Control Application is doing the same on all android versions .
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.symantec.familysafety&hl=en

Please let me know how i can get the browser history or recently navigated url from the default browser .

Comment: This may help you to get history of the default browser, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277592/how-to-retrieve-and-display-browser-history-and-bookmarks-in-browser-application?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

After long try , I think there is no default way to get the browser history so i need to use the mdm server.

https://suremdm.42gears.com

i am using this .