# Access browser history in Android for all browsers

Tags: android, browser, browser-history

I have used the Browser class to access the browsing history for my app. I just need to log/save this data. However the Android Browser class only give the browsing history of the default browser. Is it possible for me to get the browsing history in all the browsers installed in my android device.

Write now my code is as follows.

```
private String getBrowserInfo() {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    String[] proj = new String[]{Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL};
    String sel = Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK + " = 0"; // 0 = history, 1 = bookmark
    Cursor mCur = context.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, proj, sel, null, null);
    mCur.moveToFirst();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String title = "";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String url = "";
    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
        boolean cont = true;
        while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false && cont) {
            title = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE));
            url = mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
            // Do something with title and url
            mCur.moveToNext();
            stringBuffer.append("\nTitle:--- " + title + " \n" +
                    "URL:--- " + url);
            stringBuffer.append("\n----------------------------------");
        }
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Invasion of privacy. Um...

Comment: LMAO **(tongues out)**  ___OMG___

Comment: You can read it if the app allowed you to. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137339/can-we-get-chrome-browsing-history-bookmarks-in-our-android-app).

Comment: All 172 browsers available in the app store?

Comment: @Raptor Wont be a invasion of privacy if the user consents right? Plus can anonymize data easily these days right?

Comment: @323go No just the ones the user has installed in their device.