# Get Chrome history, check for keyword, and display it in TextView

Tags: android, google-chrome, history

I am trying to get the chrome history, and check for a certain keyword, and then display it in a TextView. I would appreciate some help! Thank You

Comment: Please add some more information and include what you have tried.

Comment: We would very much appreciate little bit of research from your end.

Comment: I have tried to look up how to get Chrome history to TextView but the Internet seems to be empty on this topic. I am trying now to open the history from within my application.

Comment: I searched and a Stackoverflow post came up first, try it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137339/can-we-get-chrome-browsing-history-bookmarks-in-our-android-app

Comment: I have tried this previously and my app just crashes...

Comment: Then add what you tried and post the error. Otherwise you won't get help.