# accessing browser history functions no longer available

Tags: android, browser-history

i am making an app that has to read all the browsing history of the user but the code that i got till now is all the old browser things that have been removed from android i guess, like BOOKMARKS_URI, HISTORY_PROJECTION, HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX etc, so i went to the developers site and am not getting how to access or read the browsing history of the user in my app, kindly tell me how i can read the browsing history using the classes available on the develpers site. Please help me with the code as i am new in android.

Comment: duplicates this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335175/how-to-continue-using-browser-bookmark-changes-in-android-6-0-api-23

Comment: @DaleWilson i went to the link and it says something else, i am getting errors that bla bla variable couldnot be resolved, and i want to know the solution of how can i read the browser history.