# Button click event to open bookmarks in google chrome

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an application that allows the user to access their bookmarks in Google Chrome on an `onClick` event. I have tried the following, but I get a `runtime` error on my `onClick` event

My Code is as follows

```
public void onClickbtnSavedArticles(View view) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("chrome://bookmarks/"); // missing 'http://' will cause crashed
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to find `chrome://bookmarks/`as a URL.
Any ideas on how I would go about fixing this issue?

Comment: You may want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137339/can-we-get-chrome-browsing-history-bookmarks-in-our-android-app