# Chromium browsing history in android

Tags: java, android, chromium

Can we get chromium browsing history in android app and display it into android view ? Something like `List<HistoryItem>`, is it possible ? Any help will be appreciated.

Update:
i try to deep into chromium source code and change some functionality (redesign history page) using android activity instead of html/js.

Update 2:
I am using the code from this thread to get history:
[can we get chrome browsing history/bookmarks in our android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137339/can-we-get-chrome-browsing-history-bookmarks-in-our-android-app?answertab=active#tab-top)

But this code returns only the local history. What i need to do to get a local and synced history from other devices ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the browser information from the app.

From the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

> For obvious security reasons, your application has its own cache,
>   cookie store etc.—it does not share the Browser application's data.